# Better iPhone Joystick

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, joystick, d-pad

Recently I've been working on creating Pac-Man for the iPhone. Yes, I know it's on the App store, but it's five dollars and I've had more fun making it myself. Everything works great, except for the joystick. It's not great at handling tight turns and I often double back on myself right into the ghosts. Obviously, it's incredibly frustrating. I was wondering if anyone had ran into any similar problems and what they did to fix it? Currently my joystick code looks like this:

```
-(BOOL) checkTouchesBegan: (CGPoint*) location
{
int converty = location->y-160;
int convertx = location->x-240;

float ydif = (1.0)*(converty - y);
float xdif = (1.0)*(convertx - x);
float degrees = atan2f(xdif, ydif) * 57;
float squared = xdif*xdif + ydif*ydif;

if(degrees >= 45 && degrees < 135 && sqrt(squared) < 120)
{
    direction = 1;
    return YES;
}
else if(degrees < -45 && degrees >= -135 && sqrt(squared) < 120)
{
    direction = -1;
    return YES;
}
else if(degrees >= -45 && degrees < 45 && sqrt(squared) < 120)
{
    direction = 2;
    return YES;
}
else if(sqrt(squared) < 120)
{
    direction = -2;
    return YES;
}
return NO;
```

}

Basically I check where the touch is and change the characters direction based off that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried looking at SneakyJoystick for cocos2D?

Comment: I've looked at it a little bit, but I don't think it would help much. The joystick the way I have it implemented works exactly as it should. The issue I'm having is with player control as the players thumb will sometimes slide into the wrong area, causing the player to double back on themselves right into a ghost.

Comment: Hate to say it, but that probably means you have a problem with your design of the joystick.

Comment: I agree. There is a way I can optimize the joystick so that it works more efficiently. It will take some tinkering. I was just wondering if anyone had ran into a similar issue and could give advice on what they did to improve their joystick.